# Magento1 SQL select all Attribute Option values like in Admin Backend

Tags: database, attributes, magento-1, sql

I want to get all values of all M1 Attribute Option values like in Magento backend. I have this code

```
SELECT
eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,
eav_attribute_option_value.`value`,
eav_attribute_option.attribute_id
            FROM
                    eav_attribute_option_value
            INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option ON eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
            GROUP BY
                    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id
            ORDER BY
            eav_attribute_option_value.`value` ASC
```

But I am missing the values like "Store Label", "Sort Order" and "is Default", "Store ID".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that **Is Default** is not a column but this value is exist in the main attribute table "eav_attribute", So you need also to join this table.
The same for Store label: The Store label is the value itself but the difference is in the store_id.

Please try this query and modify it depending on your needs.

```
SELECT
eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,
eav_attribute_option_value.`value`,
eav_attribute_option_value.store_id,
eav_attribute_option.attribute_id,
eav_attribute_option.sort_order,
eav_attribute.default_value
            FROM
                    eav_attribute_option_value
            INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option ON eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
            INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute_option.attribute_id
            GROUP BY
                    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,eav_attribute_option_value.`value`
            ORDER BY
            eav_attribute_option_value.`value` ASC
```

Comment: It looks like this should work.  It is worth noting that if you are looking for a specific attribute's options, you can do that by adding `where eav_attribute_option.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = '[ENTER ATTRIBUTE CODE HERE]');` between the `last inner join` and the `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query you can easily get all option values in 1 row instead different rows

```
SELECT 
    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(eav_attribute_option_value.value, ','),
    eav_attribute_option_value.store_id,
    eav_attribute_option.attribute_id,
    eav_attribute_option.sort_order,
    eav_attribute.default_value
FROM
    eav_attribute_option_value
        INNER JOIN
    eav_attribute_option ON eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
        INNER JOIN
    eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute_option.attribute_id
GROUP BY eav_attribute_option.attribute_id
ORDER BY eav_attribute_option_value.value ASC
```

Comment: Like the entry abouve but the Concat() gives bad values.

Answer (score 0):

All these solutions may misuse GROUP BY clause

Some error may occur if sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause 
and contains nonaggregated column 'clone_magento_socoda.eav_attribute_option_value.option_id' 
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

if you want all options sorted for each attribute, sorting would be a better way

```sql
SELECT
    eav_attribute_option.attribute_id, 
    eav_attribute.attribute_code,
    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,
    eav_attribute_option_value.`value`,
    eav_attribute_option_value.store_id,
    eav_attribute_option.sort_order,
    eav_attribute.default_value
    FROM eav_attribute_option_value
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option ON eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute_option.attribute_id
    ORDER BY eav_attribute_option.attribute_id, eav_attribute.attribute_code, eav_attribute_option_value.`value` ASC
```